# How to pass javascript variable value to java class

Tags: java, javascript

I want to submit data from a html page to java class. I am using javascript to get data from html page, now I want to send this data to java class to save this data to db. I am using ftl template to generate html so I cant use jsp here. Please give an example using either javascript of ajax or jquery.

thanks.

Comment: By 'java class' you mean a java servlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery to send an ajax request to your Java servlet.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/app/servlet/",
   data: {name : "John", location : "Boston"},
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Comment: `data: {name: 'John', location: 'Boston'}` would be much nicer.

Comment: Actually I am developing a plugin which concist of ftl and core java classes not servlets so I cannot use the ajax the way you suggested. Please let me know if there is another way round to pass javascript variables value to java, may be we could pass javascript varibles value to ftl variable and then pass that ftl variable to java class